# Passing an array to constructor is resulting in an array of size 1?

Tags: c++, arrays, constructor

The problem occurs when I pass nums to the declared variable third in the main file.

When I pass the array of integers in the main file to my constructor, the constructor only receives the pointer to the first array element.  How can I pass the array so that the address of the array is passed to my constructor so I can copy everything over into the member pointer of my treeArray class?

treeArray.h

```
class treeArray
{
private:
int arraySize;
int* arr;

public:
//Constructors
treeArray();
treeArray(int capacity);
treeArray(treeArray& passed); //copy constructor
treeArray(int passed[]);

//Destructor
~treeArray();

//Get Functions
int getArrCap();

//Display functions
bool displayArray();
};
```

treeArray.cpp:

```
//copy an array of ints to a treeArray
treeArray::treeArray(int passed[])
{
//get the size of the array passed and assign it to member array size
this->arraySize = sizeof(passed)/sizeof(passed[0]);

this->arr = new int[this->arraySize];

for(int i = 0; i < this->arraySize; i++)
    this->arr[i] = passed[i];
}
```

main:

```
int nums[] = {7, 9, 10, 15};

treeArray first;
treeArray second(5);
treeArray third(nums);
treeArray fourth(third);


cout << "Arrays: " << endl << "#1: ";
first.displayArray();
cout << endl << "#2: ";
second.displayArray();
cout << endl << "#3: ";
third.displayArray();
cout << endl << "#4: ";
fourth.displayArray();
cout << endl << endl;
```

Comment: You are not passing an array to the constructor (whatever you may think).  You are passing a pointer to the first element of the array.

Comment: How did I not find that page! Thanks for that, that's what I needed. And yeah I think I'll delete this question.  Thank you for your help Martin Bonner! (idk if i'm allowed to delete it or not now that I think about it)

Comment: I think *you* can close it as a duplicate.  The SO policy on duplicates is to close them, but *not* to delete them (so that other people have a better chance to find them).

Answer (score 0):

```
treeArray::treeArray(int passed[])
{
    ...
    this->arraySize = sizeof(passed)/sizeof(passed[0]);

}
```

Note `sizeof(passed)` is `sizeof(pointer-to-int)` (as in here the array decays to pointer), therefore `sizeof(passed)/sizeof(passed[0])` is usually just `1` as you noticed (as pointer is usually the same size of `int`)

It's not possible to work out the array size if you only pass array to a function. Usually an additional parameter (eg `array_size`) would be needed to be passed alongside with the array itself.

Answer (score 0):

`treeArray(int passed[]);` is equivalent to `treeArray(int* passed);`.

To have the size, you should use

```
template<std::size_t N>
treeArray(int (&passed)[N]);
```

or

```
treeArray(int passed[], std::size_t size);
```